# How to configure an app to run on all desktop automatically

Tags: kubuntu, kde, window, kwin

I'm running Kubuntu 14.04 and I'd like to have some apps to automatically be launched on all desktops and not only the current one.

As an example, I work on a dual screen and usually I have a Konsole open on my second screen, taking either the full screen, or half, or a quarter depending on what I'm doing. But almost always I want this Konsole to appear on all my four virtual desktops.

Another example would be the new [Google Hangout for Chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hangouts/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd?hl=en) with the latest Chrome (35.0) conversations are bound to the desktop you open them on, I constantly have to `right click → Move to desktop → All desktops`.

Is there a way to configure such apps to always run on all desktops ?

It seems that in the settings I could use the Window Behavior (personal translation, it may be called differently) panel to ensure that some app behave in a particular manner.

It could work for the Konsole example as the name of the window is consistently `* - Konsole` but for the Hangout one the window name is the person's full name. Any idea for this one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use hangouts, so I can't comment on the specifics, but there are alternative ways to match windows in the "Special Window Settings" (in English). If you use the window's menu to access this dialogue, it should automatically populate these fields. You can try matching by window class or window role, if either has a generic enough match.

[image]

---

If the window in question doesn't have the window decorations for you to access the menu and window settings, you can still access the popup menu by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> by default.

If this doesn't work, then you might have changed the key binding. You can check the keybinding at System Settings > Common Appearance and Behaviour > Shortcuts and Gestures > Global Keyboard Shortcuts > KWin > Window Operations Menu.

Comment: Unfortunately Hangouts' windows do not have the window manager's menu. I cant seem to find a way to activate it for these windows. But thanks, it's good to know how to do it for more classic windows. Even if I activate the system window border in chrome.

Comment: @JeremieParker Ah, right. I've added more information that should help.

Comment: That did the trick, I was able to get the menu and the window, but the pre-populated identifying information is only the fullname of the contact which is not really helpful. See https://db.tt/1OAnA0BV which is the "Detect Window Property" result of the main Hangouts window.

Comment: @JeremieParker It's odd that your window looks totally different to mine. Are you using the latest KDE? Also, I don't understand the language, but the title (Titre?) looks like it'd be consistent with different contacts?

Comment: It's the window you get when you hit the "Detect Window Property" and click on the main hangout window. Unfortunately the window title for each contact is only their fullname.

Comment: @JeremieParker Perhaps I don't understand, but was that the actual screenshot that you posted? If so, then the title (is that what "Titre" means?) looks like it's a generic "Hangouts". Why don't you try matching with that. Actually, since you mentioned you didn't have window decorations, then I think you are probably getting confused with a fake title (the contact name) that is actually a component of the window itself. The real window title ("Hangouts") is hidden in the invisible window decorations.

Comment: see this one: https://db.tt/g5Sz9OOJ its the same procedure ("Detect Window Property") but this time on a conversation with a friend. To answer your question "Titre" means "Title", it's the title of the window, if I activate window decoration, it's the title that shows up on the decoration as well.

Comment: @JeremieParker Ah okay. Then, yes, I think you are right then. There is no way to do this, apart from creating a rule for each contact…

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help anyway. I'll accept your answer for the general use case and the reminder on Alt+F3 :) !

Comment: @JeremieParker Thanks! If you want more information, you could always ask at the KDE forums. They are usually very helpful, although I'm fairly sure in this case that what you want is impossible.